# Dynamic function variable name

Tags: python-3.x, function, class

How can I call python functions using dynamic variable names? This is an example:

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a, self.b, self.c = 1, 2 ,3
    def __str__(self):
        return "a: " + str(self.a) + \
                          ", b: " + str(self.b) + \
                          ", c:" + str(self.c)       
    def inc_a(self):
        self.a += 1                          

t1 = test()
print(t1)
t1.inc_a() # this is what I DON'T want, individual increment functions
print(t1)

# I would like a inc that works like this:
# t1.inc(a) --> increase a by 1
# t1.inc(b) --> increase b by 1
# t1.inc(c) --> increase c by 1
# print(t1)
```

Thx&kind regards

Comment: any feedback? did it work?

Comment: Yes it works, many thanks (already gave you a like)! I will accept it as solution soon. I am hoping, however, that somebody will come up with a solution without quotes in the function call. I like the setattr/getattr solution a lot, but I was thinking there could be a solution similar to R's eval(substitute()). (The exec-solution looks like an equivalent for R's eval(parse(text =)).)

Comment: I'm afraid, that won't be possible to do in python. if you're calling `t.inc(a)`, `a` needs to be an already defined object/ variable else you'll get `NameError`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do it like this, using [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) :

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a, self.b, self.c = 1, 2 ,3
    def __str__(self):
        return "a: " + str(self.a) + \
                          ", b: " + str(self.b) + \
                          ", c:" + str(self.c)       
    def inc(self, v):
        exec("self.%s += 1" % (v))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
>>> t= test()
>>> print(t)
a: 1, b: 2, c:3
>>> t.inc('a')
>>> print(t)
a: 2, b: 2, c:3
>>> t.inc('b')
>>> print(t)
a: 2, b: 3, c:3
>>> t.inc('c')
>>> print(t)
a: 2, b: 3, c:4
```

However it would be better in your case to use [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) along with [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) since you're trying to set values for class variables, so your `inc` method will look something like this:

```
def inc(self, v):
    setattr(self, v, getattr(self, v)+1)
```

**Output :** same as above.